# Из за чего в XML отображает русские символы в кодировке, CMS Opencart, Google BASE?

Tags: php, xml, opencart, opencart2.0

Почему отображает русские символы в кодировке, CMS Opencart, Google BASE?
https://pipl.ua/index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где в кодировке?

Comment: Вот пример
РІРёРґРµРѕРґРѕРјРѕС„РѕРЅ DS-KH6210-L

Comment: покажите скриншот

Comment: Добавил в вопрос )

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9xPH.png

Answer (score 0):

Заменить в /catalog/controller/extension/feed/google_base.php

$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');

на

$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8');